# Switching Development/Test/Production variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-closure

I am trying to search the best approach to manage different values for same variables in Devlopment, Test and Production environment. 
For example, I have variable `jsonFile` which can be:

> `var jsonFile = http://localhost:63342/json/appsconfig.json`

for development env

> `var jsonFile = http://192.168.35.59/applications/json/appsconfig.json`

for test env

> `var jsonFile = http://example.com/applications/json/appsconfig.json`

for production env
I am trying to read a lot about Frontend Development Stack, but I am confused about what tool to use. I will use Google Closure Tools for minification, can it be also useful to switch variable values? Or can it be considered a Grunt task (even if I am not able to understand how to properly configure Grunt tasks...)?

Comment: You can use something like [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples) that is part of the "standard" grunt  In the source link, scroll down to the section labeled "Copy and modify a file" for an example of how grunt can do what you are discussing.

Answer (score 1):

What might be better is to write the JSON into a JS file that is part of your build artifacts. Something like [file-creator](https://github.com/travis-hilterbrand/grunt-file-creator) that can write a file like so (using a simplistic setup that can obviously be made more dynamic).

In the top of your module.exports for grunt tasks, load in the config file into a var like:

```
var configData = grunt.file.readJSON('../config/appsconfig.json'),
```

Then write to a new JS file using the grunt file-creator module

```
"file-creator": {
    'dev': {
        'build/config.js': function (fs, fd, done) {
                fs.writeSync(fd, 
                    'var yourSiteHere = yourSiteHere || {}; yourSiteHere.config = '
                    + JSON.stringify(configData) + ";"
                );
                done();
        }
    }
}
```

Then load this JS file into the page (perhaps even minify it using a separate grunt task). You will be then able to refer to the config data like so:

```
var apiEndPoint = yourSiteHere.config.api.apiEndPoint,
    apiKey = yourSiteHere.config.api.apiKey;
```